# Mysql 8 accidentally lost ROOT user all privileges in localhost wampserver 3.2

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-8.0

Mysql 8 root user all privileges lost.I changed some permissions from **phpmyadmin**.

. After that all tables disappeared.
I found this answer [Lost All Privileges in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990210/lost-all-privileges-in-mysql).but did'nt help me.

I am using Wampserver 3.2 on windows 7 and mysql version is 8.0.18
Now showing only information_schema table.
I login as root user and run all below commands.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+

mysql> use mysql;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'mysql;

mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table '
user';

mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost`                     |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

> How to revoke all privileges for 'ROOT' user

Please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29073563/2310830

Answer (score 3):

Thank god,Finally it worked out.
first I created a file named as `mysql-init.txt` in c drive.The file contains

```
update mysql.user
set Select_priv='Y',
    Insert_priv='Y',
    Update_priv='Y',
    Delete_priv='Y',
    Create_priv='Y',
    Drop_priv='Y',
    Reload_priv='Y',
    Shutdown_priv='Y',
    Process_priv='Y',
    File_priv='Y',
    Grant_priv='Y',
    References_priv='Y',
    Index_priv='Y',
    Alter_priv='Y',
    Show_db_priv='Y',
    Super_priv='Y',
    Create_tmp_table_priv='Y',
    Lock_tables_priv='Y',
    Execute_priv='Y',
    Repl_slave_priv='Y',
    Repl_client_priv='Y',
    Create_view_priv='Y',
    Show_view_priv='Y',
    Create_routine_priv='Y',
    Alter_routine_priv='Y',
    Create_user_priv='Y',
    Event_priv='Y',
    Trigger_priv='Y' 
where User='root';
```

Then I run this command.

```
D:\wamp3\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.18\bin>mysqld --init-file=c:\\mysql-init.txt --conso
le
```

Then login as `root` user.Now all database showing up.

Comment: a better way is a `grant all on *.* root@localhost with grant option` in the init-file. But glad it worked for you.